# d3.js plot airport map points on map with coordinates on different file

Tags: d3.js

I want to plot US airports on a map in d3.js

The source file is a csv one, which has only the airport codes, such as LAX or JFK.
The coordinates are located in a different json file.
I am using the function **plot_airports** and my issue is how to join the airport codes with the coordinates into the data variable.

```
function plot_airports(data) {
        svg.append('g')
           .attr("class", "airports")
           .selectAll("circle")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr('cx', function(d) {return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[0]; })
           .attr('cy', function(d) {return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[1]; })
           .attr('r', 5)
```

The function to read the airport code is the following:

```
d3.csv("sample.csv",function(d) {
    return d["airport"];
    });
```

and the one with the airports:

```
d3.json("airports.json");
```

I tried to save the result of each function into variables and then join them with the airport code as key but the resulting variables were empty.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d3.csv` function doesn't return a usable value that you can assign to a variable. That is, you cannot do:

```
var foo = d3.csv("sample.csv",function(d) {
    return d["airport"];
});
```

Which will simply not work.

The solution is **nesting** the two asynchronous functions:

```
d3.json("airports.json", function(dataCoordinates) {

    //get the airports coordinates in an array named 'dataCoordinates'

    d3.csv("sample.csv", function(dataCodes) {

        //get the airports codes in an array named 'dataCodes';
        //create your circles accessing both arrays, or join the arrays
        //using the airport code as key.

    });

});
```